# Minimal AngularUI page functionality not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've got the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" ng-app="app"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script>
            angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
        </script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <datepicker></datepicker>
        <timepicker></timepicker>

    </body>
</html>
```

that currently renders this datepicker and timepicker:

[image]

At first, I thought it was a problem with my code, being part of a larger site, but after reducing the template to just the basics, I'm confused as to why this doesn't work. Could anyone offer any insight as to why it's not working?

Comment: Are any javascript errors being reported by the browser?

Comment: No, the Firebug console is empty for this example. Though it's worth noting that if I use this on the full site, I get an infdig error on $rootScope. I figured if can get the example working then maybe that'll go away.

Comment: If you switch from the minified CDN to a local, non-minified version of angular.js, it should give you more helpful error messages. It also may help if you update the question with the actual HTML rendered by the directives. Also, try moving the scripts to the bottom of the page, just before `</body>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the ng-model, try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" ng-app="app"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.9.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script>
            angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <datepicker ng-model="mymodel"></datepicker>
        <timepicker ng-model="mymodel2"></timepicker>

    </body>
</html>
```

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/K1PA0T2otWzE4cXZGTPa)

Comment: So if the directive doesn't do anything without ngModel, then why do they make ngModel an optional controller?

Comment: Yep, that did it. Finally, after a few hours of table-flipping frustration. It would be nice if the docs had that too, I went off the `<datepicker min="minDate" show-weeks="showWeeks"></datepicker>` in the datepicker example. Nevertheless, thanks!

Comment: I never actually thought about it, I guess all the time I use a datepicker is to feed a model... Anyway, I agree they should include it in the example!